# Jenkins Kill Server Performance

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

So I have setup Jenkins on the smallest EC2 instance and the only major thing running on it is Jenkins (I also have apache and php installed but nothing in actively running on it.  Jenkins just seems to kill my server load.  Example is I have a server load on about 0.08 and I load the plugin manager page 3 times and that server load shoots to 1.05 (goes up to 1.99 when refreshing 10 times in a row).  Is this normal for Jenkins?  I would imagine Jenkins would perform pretty well under a small EC2 instance with nothing else major running.  The only weird thing I notice is that with htop there is 1 command running using the daemon but then 20-25 command running looking like this:

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/run/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1
```

Is it normal to have that many instances on that running with 1 instance of Jenkins?  I am just trying to figure out why Jenkins seems to be running so slow.

Comment: That does look suspicious.  Can you find out which process is consuming all the CPU ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an issue[1] with a thread dump[2]. Otherwise, complaining about a load of 1.99 on a micro EC2 isn't really going to get you anything other than laughed at..

[1] https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/
[2] https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+is+hanging